# jQuery has error of unexpected token

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I had the line of code that ran jQuery library in my header

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My javascript file sends an ajax request to a web service. The web service will output a random quote. The javascript file takes the output and displays it in a div with id='quote'. I checked the php file for web service, it worked fine and printed a random quote. But I kept getting the error below for the line with jQuery

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

And this is code from my javascript file. I also used prototype, that was why I wrote "jQuery" instead of "$"

```
function displayQuote(ajax){
    var quote = ajax.responseText;

    $("quote").hide();
    $("quote").innerHTML = quote;
    jQuery.("#quote").fadeIn(1000);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you post your responseText value as well here? Or that of your whole ajax as a JSON string?

Comment: First, you simply use the string quote as a selector, that one would never match anything, it should be $('#quote') I guess. Next jQuery has no method innerHTML, you could use $('#quote').html(quote). And just to mention you could simplify the code like: $('#quote').hide.html(quote).fadeIn(1000);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a misplaced period:

```
jQuery.("#quote").fadeIn(1000);
      ^
```

And your selectors aren't correct:

```
$("quote") // This finds a `<quote>` tag. You want `#quote`.
```

Also, use `.html()` instead of `innerHTML`:

```
function displayQuote(ajax){
    var quote = ajax.responseText;

    jQuery("#quote").hide().html(quote).fadeIn(1000);
}
```

Since you're using Prototype, take a look at [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

Answer (score 2):

```
function displayQuote(ajax){
    var quote = ajax.responseText;
    // here i added the # (hashtag) to your selector
    // when referencing an ID you need to use the hashtag '#'
    // when referencing a class you need to the a dot '.'
    $("#quote").hide();
    $("#quote").innerHTML = quote;
    // also write here you were placing a '.' after the jQuery function.
    // since this is the first function in the chain, 
    // you cannot put a period after it
    jQuery("#quote").fadeIn(1000);
 }
```

Your forgot to add the `#` hash tag when referencing the `<element id ="quote">`;

Here is another version of the same thing above:
Edit: as pointed out by [blender](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464744/blender) we cannot use `document.getElementById('')` and `fadeIn()` in the same context. So to fix this we can just reference the HTML element with `jQuery()`.

```
function displayQuote(ajax) {
           var quote = ajax.responseText;
           var quoteElement = document.getElementById('quote');
           quoteElement.style.display='none';
           quoteElement.innerHTML = quote;
           jQuery(quoteElement).fadeIn(1000);
 }
```

Comment: sorry, I also used prototype. Thats the reason for the "$"

Comment: @RPM please also add comments that what you have done! so, the OP can understand what he had a mistake in his code!

Comment: Native DOM elements don't have a `.fadeIn()` method. Wrap that element in a jQuery function.

Comment: @RPM: You don't need to find the element again. Just use `jQuery(quoteElement)` and it'll work.

Comment: @Blender Okay I wasn't aware of that. So jQuery would be using the cached selection that was gotten by `document.getElementById()`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the code should be:

```
quote.hide();
quote.innerHTML = quote;
quote.fadeIn(1000);
```

Since you already have a jQuery variable `quote`

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use that

```
function displayQuote(ajax){
    var quote = ajax.responseText;

    $("quote").hide();
    $("quote").innerHTML = quote;
    $("#quote").fadeIn(1000);
}
```